# Can I set up dual boot linux without leaving my main partition?

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, dual-boot, gentoo, macos

This might be asked already somewhere but I couldn't seem to figure out how to search exactly what I mean. I want to set up my macbook pro to dual-boot gentoo. Is it possible to set up the gentoo filesystem and install the kernel, etc from the mac partition?

I ask because I am pretty sure I have heard that dual-boot systems can be set up to access each others files. And if this is possible, I thought perhaps it could go as far as a full install.

I won't be surprised if it's not possible, just wanted to check. Thanks in advance for any tips you may have!

Edit: To clarify what I want to know. Could I theoretically set up and install a Gentoo partition all from the current OSX partition (ie. from the mac terminal, or tools like disk-utility etc)

Comment: have some external disk drive? make a 1:1 dump of your current hard drive, resize partition to minimal required, install another OS, make another 1:1 dump and restore the previous one. now copy the second dump into your main hard drive and add entry in grub https://superuser.com/q/412028

Comment: Somehow your question seems to fill my head with ideas—only I don't exactly know what they are. What do you mean by "with out leaving my main partition"? Do you mean "without deleting my existing partition"? Edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: I edited the question. What I mean is set everything up without rebooting into a live-cd etc. Just set up and access the new filesystem from my current osx partion, and only once it is all installed, I would reboot into the fresh, fully installed gentoo.

Comment: @alecxs Am I understanding you correctly, that this would mean that both the current osx partition and the new gentoo would be handled by grub, and then they could access each others files?

Comment: You can also create an image file on your existing partition and setup your initramfs to mount and boot that. I have done this before manually but don’t have the time to write up a guide/answer to doing this. But if you follow some guide on making a custom initrd/initramfs or even use something like mkinitramfs, there will be a point at which you can add custom commands to mount the root partition in a custom way. You would just mount your Mac OS X partition there and then mount your root image file as loopback and then `switch_root` to that (or just ensure it is mounted in the right path).

Comment: I am also not sure if I am understanding your question, though. Do you want to fully setup Gentoo without rebooting (you could use a VM to get you to this point)? Or do you want to avoid creating a new partition dedicated to Linux (then see my prior comment ;-))? If you are only worried about accessing each others’ files, Mac OS X supports certain Linux filesystems and Linux supports HFS+ somewhat (but doing this if you let your Mac OS X suspend to disk instead of rebooting “for real” is dangerous—maybe you just want to run Linux in a VM?).

Comment: No, it's not so much of a big deal, more a curiosity/convenience thing. I just wanted to be able to finish the install of gentoo from my mac, before rebooting into gentoo. I am quite happy to partition my disk, and not concerned about file access. After the process I want a normal dual boot gentoo install. I guess another way I could phrase the question is "Could I just use my main partition instead of a live-cd to install gentoo"

Comment: Gotta say though, there are some very cool ideas in these comments so far. So many new ideas to try